# Python Beautifulsoup parse html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse html with BeautifulSoup4:

```
<tr  class="odd" >
<td><a href="show_result.php?id=7084083" title="Show the User ID DB records for the id '7084083'"  tabindex="5" >7084083</A></td>
<td><a href="show_result.php?name=bernd" title="Show the User ID DB records the name 'bernd'"   >bernd</A></td>
<td><a href="show_result.php?range=DDF+User" title="range_link"   >DDF User</A></td>
<td>mandatory</td>
<td>Solaris</td>
<td>valid</td>
<!-- xxxx old style  -->
<!-- xxxx showdetail navlink -->
<td><a class="navlink" href="show_detail.php?rec_id=283330130"  title="show the detail for this entry [alt-E]" accesskey="E"><img src="detail.gif" alt="show the detail for this entry [alt-E]" title="show the detail for this entry [alt-E]" border="0">&nbsp;</a></td>
</tr>
```

i would like filtered out the first "id=7084083" => (7084083)

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: please dont put any code in comment section, update your post and put it in there, make sure to edit the format as well

Comment: `soup.select_one('a[tabindex]').text`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are searching for a certain, specific part of the html, it may be easier to use `re` instead of `bs4`:

```
import re
s = """
<tr  class="odd" >
<td><a href="show_result.php?id=7084083" title="Show the User ID DB records for the id '7084083'"  tabindex="5" >7084083</A></td>
<td><a href="show_result.php?name=bernd" title="Show the User ID DB records the name 'bernd'"   >bernd</A></td>
<td><a href="show_result.php?range=DDF+User" title="range_link"   >DDF User</A></td>
<td>mandatory</td>
<td>Solaris</td>
<td>valid</td>
<!-- xxxx old style  -->
<!-- xxxx showdetail navlink -->
<td><a class="navlink" href="show_detail.php?rec_id=283330130"  title="show the detail for this entry [alt-E]" accesskey="E"><img src="detail.gif" alt="show the detail for this entry [alt-E]" title="show the detail for this entry [alt-E]" border="0">&nbsp;</a></td>
</tr>
"""
final_id = re.findall('(?<=id\=)\d+', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'7084083'
```